# Applying WP-cli Search & Replace to Static SQL Dump File

Tags: customization, database, search, mysql

I have a wp db dump file inside my site directory.  Can someone show me an example of how to use wp-cli search and replace command on the static sql file, not the active db to change my url from "old-example.com" to "new-example.com"

/var/www/html/wp-site.com/dumps/oldexample.com/dumpeddb.sql

/var/www/html/wp-site.com/dumps/newexample.com/ready-for-import.sql

Not quite sure how to apply this to already exported db dump.
`$wp search-replace foo bar --export=database.sql`

Comment: `wp search-replace` will only work to the current database which is configured in `wp-config.php`

Comment: you would need to import it into a database first, you can't run an SQL query on an SQL file it has to be ran first

Comment: OK.. I was afraid of that... was trying to avoid it... always feel better know the db is healthy before importing it.  might there be a sed solution?

Comment: I found a one line solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839060/find-and-replace-text-in-the-entire-table-using-a-mysql-query  "sed -i 's/oldString/newString/g' ./db.sql"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, WP CLI uses SQL queries to acquire and update information. You would need to import the SQL file into a database to perform a search replace with WP CLI.

Comment: OK.. I was afraid of that... was trying to avoid it... always feel better know the db is healthy before importing it. might there be a sed solution?

Comment: I found a one line solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839060/find-and-replace-text-in-the-entire-table-using-a-mysql-query  "sed -i 's/oldString/newString/g' ./db.sql"

Comment: that only works because it has the same number of characters, WP CLI search replace does more than just a direct substitution. An SQL file is not a database with a health that can be queried, it's just a text file of INSERT queries